Apply Scale changing dimensions of text
I have a Text object that I've got to the size I want but when I try to Apply Scale the dimensions change (they get smaller).  Whenever I've done this previously it's just set the scale to 1 and not changed the actual dimensions of the object.  The only similar issues I could find related to the Delta Transform being the problem but I'm pretty sure mine is correct - I've certainly not touched it.  I'm very new to Blender so I'm probably doing something stupid but I'm stumped right now - any help would be appreciated.


Hello could you please share your file?

Here you go - https://wormhole.app/Rbk9Y#B9QwO0UwUU5w6ede8sux2w .  It's the Bettys Text I'm trying to apply scale to.

it looks like applying text scale works like a kind of reset, text is not a mesh object so it must explain why it works this way

I guess I must have converted the other text to a mesh before applying scale.  It's all very confusing!  Thanks for taking a look

it looks like applying text scale works like a kind of reset, text is not a mesh object so it must explain why it works this way
